# Failure to create CEF browser

Tags: codenameone

My app is failing to build or even run. It gives me an error of failure to create CEF browser.
Everything was running fine until today. I uninstalled and installed CEF again as instructed in this link : [Big Changes and CEF](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/big-changes-jcef.html) but it still gave me the error.
Here is the full error in the console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create CEF browser
[EDT] 0:0:0,40 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - Failed to create CEF browser
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:130)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:98)
    at com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent$9.run(BrowserComponent.java:557)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1338)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1280)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1162)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/falcon/.codenameone/cef/lib/linux64/libjcef.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2640)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap$1.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:24)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.cef.CefApp.startup(CefApp.java:536)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:207)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:199)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:196)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:136)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort$2.run(JavaCEFSEPort.java:120)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create screenshots for HTML <!doctype html> ...(CSS file contents)
</html>.  Timeout reached.  Likely there was a problem initializing the browser component.
    at com.codename1.designer.css.ResourcesMutator.createScreenshots(ResourcesMutator.java:668)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CSSTheme.createImageBorders(CSSTheme.java:2562)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CN1CSSCLI.compile(CN1CSSCLI.java:916)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CN1CSSCLI.main(CN1CSSCLI.java:780)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorApp._main(ResourceEditorApp.java:568)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorApp.main(ResourceEditorApp.java:258)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.CN1Bootstrap.run(CN1Bootstrap.java:218)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.CN1Bootstrap.run(CN1Bootstrap.java:96)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorApp.main(ResourceEditorApp.java:265)
/home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build.xml:625: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 2 seconds)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I have done some debugging, and I found the problem to be in my CSS file. I also debugged the CSS and realized the problem was the box-shadow property. When I commented all the box-shadow properties, everything worked as required. So why is the box-shadow property causing problems now?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/shannah/codenameone-cef/blob/master/README.adoc#unsatisfiedlinkexception-libjcefso-libjawtso) with Linux right now.

> UnsatisfiedLinkException (libjcef.so: libjawt.so)
> On Ubuntu 20, and some other versions of Linux, it has been reported that, when running the Codename One simulator with CEF installed, you get UnsatisfiedLinkException mentioning that libjcef.so could not find libjawt.so. This is caused because the lib directory of the JDK is not in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You an work around this problem by adding it. E.g.
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64

Comment: I have done that but I am still getting the same error.